# How to create a Method in C# that will allow me to prepare any insert/update statement?

Tags: c#, mysql, prepare

I am trying to write a small class that will help me to connect to MySQL server using C# and winforms. 
I wrote the connection that would start and close the connection.

What I am looking to do here is to create a method in this class to allow me to pass a query and values "in array" and the method will auto prepare the query for me.

so instead of writing a method or a code for every INSERT/UPDATE query like so...

```
    MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO mytable(a,b,c,d)VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", array_val1);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", array_val2);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", array_val3);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", array_val4);
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I would like to have a method  where I Can pass the query and the values and it will auto prepare that statement for me.

something like this

```
//Call the Method
    processQuery("INSERT INTO mytable(a,b,c,d)VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", array(1,2,3,4));
//The new Method
    public processQuery(string sqlStr, array values){

        MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = sqlStr;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", array_val1);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", array_val2);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", array_val3);
....
....
....
....
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", array_val_SIZE_OF_ARRAY);
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
```

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted or marked to close. It's an appropriate question with clear goals.

Comment: Does your code not work for some reason? Can you provide any more context around what's not working?

Comment: Do you expect that columns of differing data types will be an issue?

Comment: @JoshSmeaton, I wish thy leave a note before they down voting! any way, The intention is to make the code dynamic so I won't have to write it each time.

Comment: @HABO, They can be different yes as it should be dynamic  but I can do something like (?s,?s,?i, ?i) if this helps (s for string and i for integer

Comment: Forget all that and use Entity Framework. It's not the 90's anymore.

Comment: @HighCore Can you please explain how to do so?

Comment: @Mike not really, that would be *Too Broad* for StackOverflow. However you may want to look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723). In particular the [Get Started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907#getstarted) section.

Comment: @Mike Use sqlhelper class inside enterprise library or even better, Entity Framework as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You could have your method take in a table name and a MySqlParameter list and then craft your SQL based on what you pass in.

```
public void ProcessQuery(string tableName, MySqlParameter keyParam, params MySqlParameter[] sqlParams)
{
    using(MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
    using(MySqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
    {
        /*Update Statement*/

        //Param1 = @Param1, Param2 = @Param2, @Param3 = @Param3, etc.
        string updateParamStr = string.Join(
            ", ", 
            sqlParams.Select(sqlParam => string.Format("{0} = {1}", sqlParam.ParameterName.Substring(1), sqlParam.ParameterName)));

        //param = @param
        string keyMatchStr = string.Format("{0} = {1}", 
            keyParam.ParameterName.Substring(1),
            keyParam.ParameterName);

        string updateSql = string.Format("UPDATE {0} SET {1} WHERE {2}",
            tableName,
            updateParamStr,
            keyMatchStr);   


        /*Insert Statement*/

        //produce comma delimited list of param names with leading @ stripped eg. Param1, Param2, Param3
        string columnNameStr = string.Join(", ", sqlParams.Select(sqlParam => sqlParam.ParameterName.Substring(1)));

        //produce comma delimited list of param eg. @Param1, @Param2, @Param3
        string valueParamStr = string.Join(", ", sqlParams.Select(sqlParam => sqlParam.ParameterName));

        string insertSql = string.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2})",
            tableName,
            columnNameStr,
            valueParamStr);


        /*Combined Update and Insert*/

        string combinedSql = string.Format("{0} {1} WHERE ROW_COUNT() = 0", updateSql, insertSql);

        cmd.CommandText = combinedSql;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(keyParam);
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams);

        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

The SQL that gets generated creates a combined UPDATE and INSERT statement that looks something like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET Col1 = @Col1, Col2 = @Col2 WHERE KeyCol = @KeyCol
INSERT INTO MyTable (Col1, Col2) VALUES (@Col1, @Col2) WHERE ROW_COUNT() = 0
```

This effectively runs an UPDATE that either updates a matching row or changes nothing. In the latter case, the ROW_COUNT() will = 0 which then makes the INSERT statement do its job. We are simply leveraging the WHERE clauses in each statement to make things mutually exclusive.

You would then call the method passing a MySqlParameter for the unique key and then as many MySqlParameter objects as you like.

```
ProcessQuery(
    "MyTable",
    new MySqlParameter("@MyKeyColumn", 5)/*unique key column*/,
    new MySqlParameter("@SomeColumn", 1),
    new MySqlParameter("@SomeOtherColumn", "Some string"));
```

This has the benefit of allowing you to provide datatype information in the MySqlParameter if you so chose, or you can keep it simple with name + value pair. This does require using the @ParamName syntax instead of "?" and that the parameter names match the target columns which is clearer IMO anyway.

Comment: This is good for INSERT INTO. But how would I use this to run UPDATE....SET? or INSERT INTO ..... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE? Thanks

Comment: How are you hoping to differentiate a new vs existing record? Will you be passing in a key or identity field + value of some sort, or do you have some other mechanism in mind?

Comment: For the update I should be able to pass any insert/update and it should just process it. So in the update I will have where is = variable. For the insert into .... On duplicate key this is a mysql thing. I can identify a unique column and mysql does the insert or the update if a unique key is found